# Determine threshold value based on senstivities and specificities

Tags: r

My data is kind of irregular to apply ROC etc. for a threshold determination. To simplify, here is a demo, let `x` is

```
x<-c(0,0,0,12, 3, 4, 5, 15, 15.3, 20,18, 26)
```

Suppose `x=15.1` is the unknown true threshold and the corresponding test outcome `y` will be negative (`0`) if `x==0` OR `x > 15.1`, otherwise `y` is positive(`1`) such that:

```
y<-c(0,0,0,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0)
```

Due to `0` is a positive outcome in `x`, I'm wondering in which way I can determine the threshold of `x` to predict `y` the best. I have tried R packaged pROC and ROCR, both seem not straight forward for this situation. Would somebody have me some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a situation where you predict 0 for high values of x and predict 1 for low values of x, except you always predict 0 if x == 0. Standard packages like pROC and ROCR expect low values of x to be associated with predicting y=0. You could transform your data to this situation by:

1. Flipping the sign of all your predictions
2. Replacing 0 with a small negative value in `x`

In code (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16347508/3093387) to extract TPR and FPR for each cutoff):

```
x2 <- -x
x2[x2 == 0] <- -1000
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(x2, y)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
data.frame(cut=perf@alpha.values[[1]], fpr=perf@x.values[[1]], 
           tpr=perf@y.values[[1]])
#        cut       fpr tpr
# 1      Inf 0.0000000 0.0
# 2     -3.0 0.0000000 0.2
# 3     -4.0 0.0000000 0.4
# 4     -5.0 0.0000000 0.6
# 5    -12.0 0.0000000 0.8
# 6    -15.0 0.0000000 1.0
# 7    -15.3 0.1428571 1.0
# 8    -18.0 0.2857143 1.0
# 9    -20.0 0.4285714 1.0
# 10   -26.0 0.5714286 1.0
# 11 -1000.0 1.0000000 1.0
```

Now you can select your favorite cutoff based on the true and false positive rates, remembering that the selected cutoff value will be negated from the original value.