# Extracting thresholds or cutoff levels used to calculate ROC in R (`Epi`)

Tags: r, roc

There are solutions to extract these values in the [packages `pROC` and `ROCR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35115425/4089351), but I don't know how to do the same with the `Epi` package.

Here is the example I'm trying to work through:

```
library(pROC)
library(Epi)
data(aSAH)
ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot = "ROC", MX = T)
```

[image]

I tried the following:

```
    rc <- ROC(form = outcome ~ s100b, data=aSAH, plot="sp" )
    rc$lr$weights
    str(rc$lr$weights)
 Named num [1:113] 0.185 0.19 0.171 0.143 0.185 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:113] "29" "30" "31" "32" ..
```

which could be correct because the [documentation for the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Epi/index.html) links `weights` to the model matrix, but I am not sure, especially because he `weights` seem to start at `29`.

Comment: So why don't you use ROCR or pROC? Are they missing something else?

Comment: I am trying to sort out if the value of the predictor variable that I calculate for `lr.eta` manually corresponds to one of the threshold values that R used to calculate the ROC within the Epi package. You can see my manual calculations [here](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/roc.html).